# Dynamically generated href value disappears from its anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, popover

I created a popover that has two anchor tags, one in its header and one in its body. They're both supposed to open/download the corresponding image. The `href` values are created in a JQuery code because the user will create the images and the `id` value for each image will be loaded with Flask when the image is displayed.

The problem I'm having is that the code creates and assigns the `href` values successfully, but when I click the popover the link in the header works, but the one in the body doesn't. When I inspect this last element, the `href` value is gone from its anchor. In this image you can see the popover: [image]

I don't know javascript/jquery but this is what I came up with trying after some research:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.image-options').click(function() {
    var icon_id = $(this).attr('id');
    icon_id = "#" + icon_id
    img_id = icon_id + "mg";
    the_url = $(img_id).attr('src');

    var popString2 = "";
    popString2 = popString2 + "<a href='" + the_url + "' class='options' id='saveImage'>Save image <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-regular fa-floppy-disk'></i></span></a>";
    $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-content', popString2);

    var popString1 = "";
    popString1 = popString1 + "<a href='" + the_url + "' class='options' id='addCollection'>Add to collection <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-solid fa-plus'></i></span></a>";
    $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-original-title', popString1);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- The img id is loaded from the database. Consists of a number and 'img'. Ex. 121img -->
<img class="card-img-top card-img-bottom thumb" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" src="{{ url_for('static',filename=image[1]) }}" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'img' }}">

<!-- The popover's id is just the number plus an i. Ex. 121i -->
<a class="btn-opt btn-sm image-options" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-html="true" id="{{ image[0] ~ 'i' }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i></a>
```

In this image you can see that both values for the popover are assigned successfully: [image: popover button inspection]

But when I click the button and open the popover, the `href` value for the link in the body disappears:[image: popover button inspection].

What am I missing? Please let me know if you need additional info.

UPDATE:

I decided to remove the href from the popover header and leave only the one in the popover body. Now the problem is that I have any instances of the popover, and the link works perfectly when I open the first popover, but when I open the second one, the href disappears (the anchor tag stays, only the href disappears). It's like I can only use the variable in which I store the URL, once.

This is the new javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                  $('.image-options').click(function() {
                      var icon_id = $(this).attr('id');
                      icon_id = "#" + icon_id;
                      img_id = icon_id + "mg";
                      the_url = $(img_id).attr('src');

                      var popString2 = "";
                      popString2 = popString2 + "<a href='" + the_url + "' class='options'>Save image <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-regular fa-floppy-disk'></i></span></a>";
                      $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-content', popString2);

                      var popString1 = "";
                      popString1 = popString1 + "<a class='options'>Add to collection <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-solid fa-plus'></i></span></a>";
                      $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-original-title', popString1);
                  });
                });
```

Comment: It looks like an ID conflict (each element on the page should have unique one). Have you tried to write image_id (received from flask) to any other attribute insead of id? For example data-image-id (you can get it in js by "var icon_id = $(this).data('image-id')")

Comment: I did a few tests to check if it was an ID conflict but found that it was not. The problem is with the href attribute. It's assigned successfully in the first popover I click, but not in others after. The HTML code is loaded to the popover, so I know it's not an ID issue, but the href just disappears.

Comment: Ok let me check again

Comment: So my suggestion now it that you don't need to run your js script each click. Please try to replace `$('.image-options').click(function() {` to `$('.image-options').each(function() {` and let me know if it helps

Comment: Changed it but same result :/ @akdev

Comment: Now you have only id (without postfix) at <a> element. But in js you are adding 'mg' postfix. I've tried it and got href='undefined' (which is close to your disappearing href attribute behavior). Maybe it should be 'img' postfix?

Also could you please update to the current versions of js and html?

Comment: The id at <a> has the postfix 'i', that's why I only add 'mg' in js. On my way to updating js and HTML. Thanks for the time you're taking to review my code!

Comment: Done. Only had to update the js.

Comment: Please check this example https://www.codeply.com/p/a7ns9i9VZy

I have added two images and two links. Then I run js once at document load. Toggling popovers in and out keeps links and hrefs working fine

Comment: Can you explain what the last two lines of code do? I copied and pasted your code but now the popovers are not even opening. Maybe I need to change something in my HTML code to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#enable-popovers
It is just initializing of popover. You can delete these lines if popovers worked before

Comment: maybe you can share the full page? it will be much easier to debug what actually happens

Comment: I'm working on it locally. I could post the entire simplified page code.

Comment: Solved it! Just added this to the head of the page: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> Thank you so much @akdev!

Comment: Wow it's great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINAL UPDATE:

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.image-options').each(function() {
      var icon_id = $(this).attr('id');
      icon_id = "#" + icon_id;
      img_id = icon_id + "mg";
      the_url = $(img_id).attr('src');

      var popString2 = "";
      popString2 = popString2 + "<a href='" + the_url + "' class='options'>Save image <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-regular fa-floppy-disk'></i></span></a>";
      $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-content', popString2);

      var popString1 = "";
      popString1 = popString1 + "<a href='' class='options'>Add to collection <span class='icon-pop'><i class='fa-solid fa-plus'></i></span></a>";
      $(icon_id).attr('data-bs-title', popString1);
    });
      $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
  });
```

HTML code remained the same.